# Conditional types TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I don't know if I'm searching well, but I'd like to do something like a conditional type.
I would like to transform this type in my project:

```
type CommonProps = {
    duration: number;
    type?: 'primary' | 'secondary';
    variant?: 'linear' | 'circular' | 'square'
}
```

It should work on a principles: If a `primary` type has been selected, variant is available: `'linear' | 'circular' | 'square'` but if `secondary` type has been selected, variant is available: `'linear' | 'circular'`.

I tried to transform it to:

```
type CommonProps = {
    duration: number;
}& {
    type?: 'primary'
    variant?: 'linear' | 'circular' | 'square'
} & {
    type?:  'secondary';
    variant?: 'linear' | 'circular'
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not meet expectations as there is a problem with this use later in the code for example: `styles[type][variant];`.

Comment: You are probably looking for [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest another solution just using Generics.

```
type CommonProps<T extends 'primary' | 'secondary'> = {
  duration: number;
  type?: T;
  variant?: T extends 'primary' ? 'linear' | 'circular' | 'square' : T extends 'secondary' ? 'linear' | 'circular' : undefined;
};

const foo: CommonProps<'secondary'> = {
  type: 'secondary',
  variant: 'square' // error square is not part of the variants for secondary
}
```

Comment: While clever, ths isn't as readable or obvious as the other approach taken by @JaredSmith.

Comment: Thank you it is what  I was looking for. I even looked at something similar in the documentation, but didn't quite know how to apply it. Thank you again

Comment: Yeah that's absolutely true =) That's why I said it's *another* solution, not **the** solution ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by discriminating on the type property in the union of two different types:

```js
type PrimaryProps = {
    duration: number;
    type?: 'primary';
    variant?: 'linear' | 'circular' | 'square'
}

type SecondaryProps = {
    duration: number;
    type?: 'secondary';
    variant?: 'linear' | 'circular'
}

function foo(a: PrimaryProps | SecondaryProps) {
  switch (a.type) {
    case 'primary':
      a.variant = 'linear';   // fine
      a.variant = 'circular'; // fine
      a.variant = 'square';   // fine
      a.variant = 'pizza';    // fails as expected
      break;
    case 'secondary':
      a.variant = 'linear';   // fine
      a.variant = 'circular'; // fine
      a.variant = 'square';   // fails, can't have square w/secondary
      break;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYEM4ngezAZygXigG8BYAKCkqgBMBXOFYBTAOwC4oXakAjCOANzkqUUJAD8HAORhEqdFKEUqANzQIULYJKhSANghYQ0UqAB9dAYwRxLtPSfO6cAR1poIU8gF9y5MdAAyhCWrNRoGHDYeISkypR0DEysHFy8-EoiATpSOCFhEYrCquqa2tIGRo4WUta29iY+fmQAZrQslsksUC2YmAAUKBzwyBFYuE7BoSzh6OM4AJTExTgA7gjAlgAWUIMAdAFLcSKWKHm6sqMKbMUiKHtqiGUEupXGcEXxVPePGlovtRsdgcH0yIigP1K-0IuTcHk+4IhDyhwABYAQAC8MSgEeCeHBjABrMGUU7nXL5GaFG5fSiQp7Q16Gd64u7IhmomF1YEmEnfdl-TnOOEE1n837PGHorE4vmUfFEsG+MjKoA)